# How to register for a custom event on an office add-in from .net

Tags: .net, com, event-handling, office-addins

I'm trying to write an add-in for Word 2010 that will allow .NET applications to register for custom events from the add-in. I have it mostly working, in that my add-in runs correctly and can pass an object to my .NET piece that implements an interface usable by the .NET app. This works fine for basic method calls, but when I try to register for an event declared in the interface, I get this exception:

`Unable to cast object of type 'System.__ComObject' to type 'System.EventHandler'.`

Here's my relevant code:

Add-in class:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private ExposedObject _obj;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.DocumentBeforeSave += Application_DocumentBeforeSave;
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        void Application_DocumentBeforeSave(Word.Document Doc, ref bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            Doc.Paragraphs[1].Range.InsertParagraphBefore();
            Doc.Paragraphs[1].Range.Text = "This text was added by using code.";

            if (_obj != null)
            {
                _obj.DispatchUserActivityStarted();
            }
        }

        protected override object RequestComAddInAutomationService()
        {
            if (_obj == null)
            {
                _obj = new ExposedObject();
            }

            return _obj;
        }
    }
```

Here's the class for the object that's shared from the add-in to the .NET app:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class ExposedObject : StandardOleMarshalObject, IDocumentProcessor
{
    public event EventHandler UserActivityStarted;

    //same namespace as add-in
    internal void DispatchUserActivityStarted()
    {
        if (UserActivityStarted != null)
        {
            UserActivityStarted.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the interface being used by the shared object:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IDocumentProcessor
{
    event EventHandler UserActivityStarted;
}
```

Lastly, here's how the .NET app is trying to use the add-in:

```
var word = new Application();
word.Visible = true;
object addinName = "SampleWordAddIn";
var addin = word.Application.COMAddIns.Item(ref addinName);
var addinObject = (IDocumentProcessor) addin.Object;
addinObject.UserActivityStarted += OnUserActivityStarted;

private void OnUserActivityStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Everything works fine up until the line where `addinObject.UserActivityStarted += OnUserActivityStarted;` is being called, which is where the exception is thrown. What do I need to do in order to attach to events in this case?